# Cannot read properties of undefined (React)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, jsx

I have an issue with my code, i have a search input and a list of countries

When i type some words i have an error which cause to my app collapse

I've been trying for about two days to find the problem but can't find it.

This is the error message : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')

```
const Country = ({name, num}) =>{
//console.log(name)  
return (
    <div>
        <p>{name}</p>
    </div>
)} // Component

const Input = ({onSearch, search}) =>{

return (
    <div>
        Find countries: <input onChange={onSearch} value={search} />
    </div>
)} // Component

    import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Input from "./components/Input";
import Country from "./components/Country";
const App = () => {
  const [countryList, setCountryList] = useState();
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all")
      .then((res) => setCountryList(res.data));
  }, []);
  const onSearch = (event) => {
    if (event.target.value === " ") setFilter(false);
    else {
      setFilter(true);
      setSearch(event.target.value);
    }
  };

  const countriesList = filter 
    ? countryList.filter((country) => {
        return country.name.common.includes(search);
      })
    : null ;

  return (
    <div>
      <Input onSearch={onSearch} search={search} />
      {filter ? (
        countriesList.length === 0 ? (
          <h3>No match</h3>
        ) : countriesList.length > 10 ? (
          <h3>Too many matches, specify another filter...</h3>
        ) : countriesList.length < 10 && countriesList.length > 1 ? (
          countriesList.map((country, i) => (
            <Country name={country.name.common} key={i} num={false} />
          ))
        ) : (
          <Country name={countriesList[0].name.common} num={true} /> &&
          console.log("common", countriesList)
        )
      ) : (
        <h3>Search for any country</h3>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: `useEffect` is executed only after the component has been rendered therefore, at the very beginning, `countryList` is `undefined` and `countryList.filter` will give you that error. One way to avoid it is to initialize `countryList` to an empty array (`const [countryList, setCountryList] = useState([]);`)

Answer (score 1):

countrylist state must be an array.

Answer (score 1):

Try using array in countyList as its undefined initially

```
const [countryList, setCountryList] = useState([]);
```

Also you seems to be you accessing filter (a state value directly while component initilize). Please try replacing with below code. Let me know if issue persists, should be a very simple fix

```
    const [countriesList, setCountriesList] = useState([]);
    useEffect(()=>{
            if(filter){
                setCountriesList(
                   countryList.filter((country) => {
                   return country?.name?.common?.includes(search);
                }))
             }else{
                setCountriesList(countryList);
             }
    },[filter])
```

Comment: But the useEffect only execute once right ?

Comment: Yes, if you want to trigger it based on the filter then you can add a dependency, edited the answer.

Comment: Edited: So whenever filter will change then useEffect will ve executed. I guess this fixes all for you. If so, please mark it as answered.